# responsiveness discrepancy between browser view and actual device

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have designed a fully responsive web page using Reactjs on the browser, but when I opened it on a real phone, there were things that are "off", although I designed it on the browser for the same phone. Why is that? I have that meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` set in the `index.html`. The problem with this I would never know how it would look like on the real device before deployment, which is time-consuming and tedious. Why is this happening?

Comment: please provide some code or any screenshot to understand

Answer (score 0):

The browser engine on your computer and on your phone might not be the same.

Are you using the same browser on both? like chrome??

If that is not the case, there will be some differences.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, no, they are not the same. On my computer it's Chrome, but on my phone it's Safari (the default browser for iPhone). So, different browsers will output different things, even if everything is supported in both?

Comment: Yes. Because some css attributes may not be supported. And also for some of the native implementation, all browsers use their own which is sometimes little bit off.

Comment: So, in this case, how to know if my design works on all most used browsers before deploying? For example, I use Windows on my computer, and Safari is not available on Windows as far as I know.

Comment: Try using https://www.browserling.com for testing different browsers and versions.